# Как отправлять определенные данные в curl

Tags: html, консоль, flask, curl

Допустим есть сайт ifconfig.net, если перейти на него в браузере, то откроется, соответственно, сайт, но если в консоли написать `curl ifconfig.net`, то вместо кода страницы консоль напишет вам ваш айпи адрес, как можно подобное повторить в html? Чтобы например при получении сайта через curl он писал мне не `<html> <body>...` а определенный текст, например test? Заранее спасибо, надеюсь смог объяснить.

Answer (score 1):

Сайт ifconfig.net смотрит заголовок User-Agent и если понимает, что запрос делают курлом, возвращает ответ обычным текстом.
Попробуйте

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)" ifconfig.net
```

Тут curl притворяется браузером.

Это особенность конкретного сайта. Его создатель написал такую обработку запросов специально под курл. Другие сайты могут всегда возвращать html.
Сам curl парсить html не умеет. Можно разве что по pipe передать вывод curl какому-нибудь консольному html парсеру.

Comment: Спасибо, но я не смог найти ничего связанного с юзер агентом в коде сайта, можете пожалуйста дать наводку?

Comment: А вам и не доступен код их сайта, если вы не его владелец или разработчик. Это делается на бекэнде. А какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить? Может вы пошли не в ту сторону с курлом изначально.

Comment: @Zailox
Хотя код доступен в opensource. Вот собственно код сайта
https://github.com/mpolden/echoip/blob/master/http/http.go

Обратите внимание на функцию cliMatcher

Comment: спасибо, насчёт задачи - пока что сделать такой же сайт, просто для себя